# Call javascript function on every page show. (php get variables)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this JavaScript function in the header of my site. On first page load everything works as expected, i get the response back onsuccess is fired and it updates the div tag specified.

I use `var reqid = "<?= $_GET['id']; ?>";`  to get the id of the page.

When i navigate through my app and load the same page but with a different id in the url string `var reqid = "<?= $_GET['id']; ?>";`  does not update and reverts to the previous value. how can i get this to update every time the page is shown?

```
            var request = function() {
             function onSuccess(data, status)
        {
         $("#notif").fadeIn(2000);
            data = $.trim(data);
            if(data == "SUCCESS"){
           $("#notif").html('<div class="notification-box-green">  <img class="notification-icon" src="images/lists/list-tick.png" alt=""> <p class="notification-text">Success!</p></div>').fadeIn(4000);
           $('#notif').fadeOut(4000, function() {
  });
            }  else  if(data == "LIMIT")
            {
            $("#notif").html('<div class="notification-box-yellow"><img class="notification-icon" src="images/lists/list-warning.png" alt=""><p class="notification-text">Please Wait!</p></div>').fadeIn(4000);
           $('#notif').fadeOut(4000, function() {
  });
            }    else  if(data == "NO_WIFI")
            {
            $("#notif").html('<div class="notification-box-yellow"><img class="notification-icon" src="images/lists/list-warning.png" alt=""><p class="notification-text">Connect to hostspot!</p></div>').fadeIn(4000);
           $('#notif').fadeOut(4000, function() {
  });
            }

}
                 var reqid = "<?= $_GET['id']; ?>";
                      $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                          url: "req_sub.php",
                                      cache: false,
                                                      data: "id="+ reqid,
                                                      success: onSuccess
                                      });

        }
```

The function is called with a button click.

*EDIT*

I modified my code slightly and placed it into its own js file.

the id now seems to update as expected.

one problem still remains, the code in onsuccess doesnt execute second time round.  first load or on a refresh the div changes as expected, navigation back to the page with a different id in the url doesnt update the div.

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}




            var request = function() {
          var reqid = getUrlVars()["id"]; 
             function onSuccess(data, status)
        {
```

*Edit 2*

I cloned the div and replaced it when i was done.

```
         var divClone = $("#notif").clone(); 
            var request = function() {
          var reqid = getUrlVars()["id"]; 
             function onSuccess(data, status)
        {


         $("#notif").fadeIn(2000);
            data = $.trim(data);
            if(data == "SUCCESS"){
           $("#notif").html('<div class="notification-box-green">  <img class="notification-icon" src="images/lists/list-tick.png" alt=""> <p 

class="notification-text">Success!</p></div>').fadeIn(4000);
           $('#notif').fadeOut(4000, function() {




$("#notif").replaceWith(divClone);
```

Doubt this has been the proper way to achieve my goal, will further test after sleep and update with results.

Comment: I think you are seeing some cached page

Comment: Check your page source and see what PHP is generating for `<?= $_GET['id'] ?>`. It should be whatever the `id` query parameter is set to

Comment: i checked it does not change, strange thing is it has been working fine for months and all of a sudden its not.  See update on my question.